Bootstrap 5 collapse positioning when using buttons arranged as a responsive grid
I have never had to worry about reponsive design before, because previously all programs have been used solely on laptops. However now "customer" wants one unit of a program to be useable on phones/tablets as well.
Program is basic Bootstrap5 HTML with PHP backend (which is not relevent to this query.
I have 12 buttons (months) arranged, by default as a 4 row 3 column grid on a large screen, but this reduces down to 1 button wide of a phone screen.
On the wider screens clicking a button causes a collapsed div to open immediately below the button row, collapse div takes full width of available screen. (e.g. click February button and collapse opens below January/February/March row)
If the button is clicked when on a phone screen the customer would like the collapse to open immediately below the selected button, but currently it opens below the "third button of the current row" (e.g click February button and collapse opens below the March button)
The code used for the buttons:
        <div class="container mt-5" id="groupowner">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse01" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse01">
                    January
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse02" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse02">
                    February
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse03" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse03">
                    March
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapse01" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    Collapsible content for January.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapse02" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    Collapsible content for February.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapse03" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    Collapsible content for March.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse04" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse04">
                    April
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse05" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse05">
                    May
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse06" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse06">
                    June
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapse04" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
            <div class="card card-body">
                Collapsible content for April.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse05" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
            <div class="card card-body">
                Collapsible content for May.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse06" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
            <div class="card card-body">
                Collapsible content for June.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse07" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse07">
                    July
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse08" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse08">
                    August
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse09" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse09">
                    September
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapse07" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
            <div class="card card-body">
                Collapsible content for July.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse08" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
            <div class="card card-body">
                Collapsible content for August.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse09" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
            <div class="card card-body">
                Collapsible content for September.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse10" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse10">
                    October
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse11" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse11">
                    November
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-100" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse12" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse12">
                    December
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapse10" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
            <div class="card card-body">
                Collapsible content for October.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse11" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
            <div class="card card-body">
                Collapsible content for November.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse12" data-bs-parent="#groupowner">
            <div class="card card-body">
                Collapsible content for December.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

If I move each collapse immediately below its corresponding button it works correctly on the small viewport, but throws the grid out on larger viewports.
I am sure I have seen something similar done, but using, I think, Bootstrap 3, but I have been unable to find it either on SO or using search engines.
Many thanks for comments.
